# header('Location: <anchor>') in PHP does not always work in IE11

Tags: php, html

I cannot figure out why sometimes IE11 does not go to anchor after header location is done.

I have this in PHP:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '#order-a');
```

In HTML I tried both a `name=` and `id=`, neather one is working properly in IE with `header('Location:`.

The problem is: after `header('Location: '` is done it should reload and scroll to the anchor. This is working in FF, Chrome and even in IE11 but my problem is that in IE11 it **sometimes** does not scroll to the anchor. (approximately in one of five cases).

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the javascript that makes you scroll to the selected anchor?

Comment: @HomelessPerson He's not using Javascript, he's just putting `#anchor` in the URL. The browser should scroll to it automatically.

Comment: Are you sure there's enough room after the anchor for it to scroll down to it?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, there is plenty of room. And also it does work sometimes. Thats what bothers me.

Comment: Missed the comment about it not being javascript or jquery. Found this link that it is known to break on internet explorer. You will have to live with it I guess. [link](https://chrisjean.com/links-to-named-anchors-or-element-ids-fail-in-ie8/)

Comment: @TomKriek I found the same link before but this does not seems to be the issue. The bug was in IE8. Even the example of the bug on the very same page is working properly in IE11. (and just to be sure I tried their workaround and still works only sometimes in IE11.)

Comment: Can you post the markup surrounding the tag you want to scroll to?

Comment: Chrome also ignores the URL fragment sometimes or jumps way **after** the indicated anchor. Firefox also does it in some contexts. I think it is a common disease of the modern browsers and maybe it is caused by the big amount of CSS positioning and dynamically generated and modified HTML (just a guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP.)*

Thanks to the questions in the comments that pointed me to the right direction I was exploring the issue more and did an example: input submitted -> `header('Location: <with anchor>')` and it was working even in IE. So I assumed that the problem is not actually in `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '#order-a');` and IE because that is valid.

Therefore I went through my website code again and realized that the `<a name="order-a"></a>` is inside div that has style `display: none` and this div switches (thanks to JavaScript) to style display block after #order-a is contained in URL.

So when I submitted, PHP says go to `#order-a` but by that time `#order-a` has display none so it won't move to the anchor but add `#order-a` to the URL - thanks to it JavaScript does its job and set a div that contains `#order-a` to display block.

After I realized that, I just added to my JS a code that goes to the anchor after its div has display block. And it's working, thank you all for pointing me to the right direction with your questions.